# glfw/glfw3.h': No such file or directory

Tags: glfw, vulkan

When trying to run a Vulkan project in VS 2022 on Windows 11, it just throws this error:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'glfw/glfw3.h': No such file or directory
```

In the main .hpp file, I use:

```
#include <glfw/glfw3.h>
```

The Configuration Properties->C/C++ Additional Include Directories has this line:

```
C:\Users\Me\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\Libraries\glfw-3.3.5.bin.WIN64\include
```

The glfw3.h is located at:

```
"C:\Users\Me\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\Libraries\glfw-3.3.5.bin.WIN64\include\glfw\glfw3.h"
```

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure the same setting is specified for all relevant configurations (e.g., Debug, Release) and platforms (e.g., Win32, x64)? A common mistake novices do with project settings in VS is they accidentally change only certain configurations/platforms and then actually build another ones.

Comment: Properties are set for "All Configurations" and the Platform "Active(x64)".  When switching the configuration to "Active(Debug)", it also shows the correct additional library directories.